# How to compile Qt for 64-bit Windows from a 32-bit environment with Visual C++ 2010 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, 64-bit, visual-studio-express

I am trying to compile the Qt library (I don't need the demos or examples) for 64-bit Windows. There are instructions [here](https://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_build_64_bit_qt_on_a_32_bit_system) but I run into the error described in the comment below it. There doesn't seem to be a reference anywhere for how one might go about doing this process.

I am targetting Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express. It looks like I need Perl and the Windows SDK as well - how do I go about this process?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This process is quite tedious and time-consuming - but I will explain each step in detail here for the benefit of others who try to compile Qt in the future.

1. The first step is to install all of the prerequisites.

   - [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads), which is used during the configuration process. You will need to restart after installing Perl since it modifies environment variables.
   - The [Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279) (formerly called the Platform SDK). Be sure to include the x64 libraries when you select the components to install.
2. Download the Qt source archive from the [Qt Downloads page](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/).
3. Extract the contents of the archive to an easy-to-remember location (like `C:\`). You need to remember this location later since we will be using it to set some environment variables.
4. Now open the Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt. Begin by setting the environment to 32-bit release mode (we need to build some of the tools as 32-bit applications):

   ```
   setenv /release /x86
   ```
5. Set the following environment variables (example below assumes you extracted to `C:\`):

   ```
   set QTDIR=C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.0
   set PATH=%PATH%;%QTDIR%\bin
   ```
6. Now run `cd %QTDIR%` and specify the configuration options - example is included below:

   ```
   configure -release -opensource -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libmng -qt-libtiff
    -qt-libjpeg -qt-style-windowsxp -qt-style-windowsvista -platform
    win32-msvc2010
   ```
7. Once the configuration process is complete, `cd` to the `src` directory and run:

   ```
   qmake
   nmake
   ```

   This process may take a considerable amount of time, so now would be a good time to take a break and answer some questions here on Stack Overflow :)
8. The tools are now built and you need to compile Qt as a 64-bit library. Enter the following command:

   ```
   setenv /x64
   ```

   You will need to set the environment variables from step 5 again. Enter those commands now.
9. Run `cd %QTDIR%` and then rerun the `configure` command **being sure to specify one additional option**:

   ```
   configure -release -opensource -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libmng -qt-libtiff
    -qt-libjpeg -qt-style-windowsxp -qt-style-windowsvista -platform
    win32-msvc2010 -no-qmake
   ```

   The `-no-qmake` option is very important - it indicates that we want to skip the compilation of the `qmake.exe` program because we want to keep the 32-bit version.
10. Now things get really complicated here because of some dependency problems. The tools (like `moc`) that Qt needs to build the core library and some of the other components are listed as dependencies in the `src.pro` file. This means that the compiler will attempt to build them as 64-bit applications and then try to run them - which will of course fail on a 32-bit system. So what we need to do is edit `src.pro` and remove those dependencies ourselves. Scroll down near line 85 and look for a line that begins with:

    ```
    !wince*:!ordered:!symbian-abld:!symbian-sbsv2 {
    ```

    Each subsequent line in the section lists a sub-target and its dependencies. What you want to do now is remove all dependencies that begin with `src_tools_`. For example:

    ```
    src_gui.depends = src_corelib src_tools_uic
    ```

    Becomes:

    ```
    src_gui.depends = src_corelib
    ```

    There might be a better way of doing this, but I haven't figured it out yet :)
11. Now we `cd` into the `src` directory once again and run the following command

    ```
    nmake sub-winmain sub-corelib sub-xml sub-network sub-sql sub-testlib
     sub-gui sub-qt3support sub-activeqt sub-opengl sub-xmlpatterns sub-phonon
     sub-multimedia sub-svg sub-script sub-declarative sub-webkit
     sub-scripttools sub-plugins sub-imports
    ```

    This builds *only* the Qt libraries and skips the tool dependencies. Note that this too may take a considerable amount of time.
12. You should now have 64-bit libraries in the `lib` folder that you can link against in your 64-bit Qt applications.

---

**Edit:** it turns out that even this wasn't enough since I still ran into some problems when linking the `QtWebKit4.dll` library (something about unresolved symbols). It turns out that [someone else has already found the solution](http://blog.inventic.eu/2011/01/problem-with-qt-compilation-under-windows-64-bit/) and you need to change `QMAKE_HOST.arch` to `QMAKE_TARGET.arch` in `WebCore.pro`.

Also, the above options will build QNetwork4.dll without OpenSSL support (you won't be able to access sites over HTTPS - even in a QWebView). This, thankfully isn't too hard to fix. Download and build [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) for Win64 and append the options below to the command in step #9:

```
-openssl -I C:\OpenSSL\inc32 -L C:\OpenSSL\out32dll
```

(You'll have to change the paths if you installed OpenSSL somewhere other than `C:\OpenSSL`.)

---

**Further edit:** to save the trouble of doing this yourself, I have uploaded the compiled libraries here:
http://www.box.com/s/9710cbb278ef4890a7b5

Comment: And yet people still talk about Qt like it's this panacea in app development, that it's beautiful and simple and *easy*. I've yet to see any evidence of this. When I tried working with it, my conclusion is it's just not worth it, especially considering that once you get through, you still don't have a fully native application.

Comment: @CodyGray: Completely disagree - why else would you go through this much trouble to use it?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: I am compiling my Qt application with your compiled 64-bit binaries, but my application crashes. I think that this has to do with the fact that I used a QTableView, which crashes due to a bug in the MS Visual C++ compiler, see https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-19175 and https://bugreports.qt-project.org//browse/QTBUG-11445 . Did you use MSVC SP 1 to compile the binaries? I'm recompiling Qt 64-bit myself now, but I'm asking this because I think your uploaded compiled libraries are probably useful for others too and it is therefore important for them to be bug-free.

Comment: @Yori: I'm not exactly sure - I used whatever currently ships with the Windows SDK 7.1.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: I just re-compiled the Qt libraries after installing a hotfix for MSVC from Microsoft, and it did fix the crashes. So it seems that your binaries may indeed be affected by the bug.  Would it be possible for you to recompile and upload the binaries after installing SP1? (I'd be happy to contribute but you seem to be much more experienced and knowledgeable about this than I am) This is, by the way, one of the reasons why there is no 64-bit Qt binary available on the Qt website.

Comment: @Yori: Well to be honest, my computer's configuration changes a lot so I don't have easy access to my MSVC installation right now. If you have built them successfully, that's excellent and I have no objections to you uploading your build somewhere and linking to it here.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments to George Edison's answer, there is a bug in the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler that comes with the Windows SDK 7.1. For more information on this, see [QTBUG-11445](https://bugreports.qt-project.org//browse/QTBUG-11445) and [QTBUG-19175](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-19175).

I have compiled the Qt 4.8.2 64-bit binaries following George's instructions, including the OpenSSH library. In addition, I applied [Microsoft's hotfix](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=31433) to fix the compiler bug.

For your convenience, I have made the resulting 64-bit libraries available for download from here: https://www.box.com/s/8948c60c3cdd743ef83b

Comment: I too face the same Compatibility issue then I have installed SDK 7.0 and referrd this method and its working for me http://qtitkvtkhelp.blogspot.in/2013/04/qt-64-bit-build.html